# Cloning nodes and appending to separate Layers in React-Konva

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas, konvajs

I'm trying to recreate an effect similar to the hover effect found on this site: http://tabotabo.com

Currently, what I'm doing is have the video playing on a layer with a second scaled up layer also playing the video with an additional Text object with a `destination-in` compositing operation. This is currently working well enough but I was curious if there would be a more efficient way to achieve this by either caching or cloning the first layer and sending that through to the second layer instead of having two separate video objects running in tandem.

Here is the relevant code, if it helps.

**Main Render:**

```
<Stage width={width} height={height} ref={ref => (this.stage = ref)}>
  <Layer hitGraphEnabled={false}>
    <CanvasVideo
      src={this.state.background} 
      settings={{id: 'main', width: width, height: height }}
      ref={(el) => this.main = el }
    />
  </Layer>

  <Layer hitGraphEnabled={false} scaleX={hoverScale} scaleY={hoverScale} x={scaleOffsetX} y={scaleOffsetY}>
    <CanvasVideo
      src={this.state.background} 
      settings={{id: 'main2', width: width, height: height }}
      ref={(el) => this.main2 = el }
    />

    <Text 
      id="hoverText"
      text={this.state.menu.hoverText}
      globalCompositeOperation='destination-in'
      fontSize={200}
      fill="white"
      opacity={hoverOpacity} 
      height={height}
      width={width}
      align="center"
      verticalAlign='middle'
    />
  </Layer>
</Stage>
```

**Video Container Class:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Konva from 'konva';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Stage, Layer, Image } from 'react-konva';

class CanvasVideo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      const video = document.createElement('video');
      video.muted = true;
      video.autoplay = false;
      video.loop = true;
      video.src = props.src;
      this.state = {
        video: video
      };
      video.addEventListener('canplay', () => {
        video.play();
        this.image.getLayer().batchDraw();
        this.requestUpdate();
      });

    }

    requestUpdate = () => {
      this.image.getLayer().batchDraw();
      requestAnimationFrame(this.requestUpdate);
    }
    render() {
      let { settings } = this.props
        return (
            <Image
              {...settings}
              image={this.state.video}
              ref={node => { this.image = node; }}
            />
        );
    }
}

CanvasVideo.defaultProps = {
  settings: null,
};

export default CanvasVideo;
```

Any explanations or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to reuse `Konva.Image` or any other `Konva.Node` inside different parents. `Konva.Node` can have only one parent.

I see only one optimization here is to reuse `<video>` element you created in `CanvasVideo` component. It can be like this:

```
const cache = {};

function createVideo(url) {
   if (cache[url]) {
      return cache[url];
   }
   const video = document.createElement('video');
   video.src = url;
   cache[url] = video;
   return video;
}

const video = createVideo(props.src);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! How would you recommend doing that? Within the `CanvasVideo` component itself? I've tried creating a single instance of that component in the parent but have gotten errors such as "Objects are not valid as a React child."  Thanks again :]